How to split a dataset into folders depending in its labels?
I have an images dataset in one folder and I want to separate it into folders depending on a csv file containing all images IDs and their labels, so I want to read, check and separate. Also, I want to work on Kaggle, so is it possible if I want to save the output in the working directory?
I tried the following code, but it is not working in a certain point.
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil

# Dump all images into a folder and specify the path:
data_dir = os.getcwd() + "/data/all_images/"

# Path to destination directory where we want subfolders
dest_dir = os.getcwd() + "/data/reorganized/"

# Read the csv file containing image names and corresponding labels
df = pd.read_csv('data/metadata.csv')
print(df['dx'].value_counts())

label=df['dx'].unique().tolist()  #Extract labels into a list
label_images = []


# Copy images to new folders
for i in label:
    os.mkdir(dest_dir + str(i) + "/")
    sample = df[df['dx'] == i]['image_id']
    label_images.extend(sample)
    for id in label_images:
        shutil.copyfile((data_dir + "/"+ id +".jpg"), (dest_dir + i + "/"+id+".jpg"))
    label_images=[]  

